# Angular, how to sort correctly the date in the string the strings?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have these two strings:

```
"2022 | Dec (V2 2022)"
"2022 | Jul (V1 2022)"
```

And I want to sort them correctly, for now, I am using **localeCompare** but doesn't work properly
As I get ***"2022 | Jul (V1 2022)"***, the second and it should be the first.
Can sb help me, please?

Comment: Sounds like you want to convert these strings into a date and then sort by that. You could create a custom sort pipe to do that and call that either in the template or call the function in code. Start by researching and then implementing something that can parse these strings into a date. Then add the code to sort by that date. Then implement that in your project. Good luck and if you get stuck on a *specific* problem update your question or ask a new one.

Comment: I don't really know how to do that, can you provide me an example, please?
I would really appreciate, i am totally new with angular

Comment: You can use your browser and favorite search engine and start searching on how to do each part of what I mentioned before. How to parse a string to date in javascript/typescript has been asked many times before as well as how to sort dates.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask), [*Writing the Perfect Question*](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask), and [*What topics can I ask about here?*](/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to convert your strings into **date** objects first and then you can perform sorting.

Now your strings are in a specific format that no date library would recognize (so you'll have to devise your own strategy to convert the strings into date)

You can take help from **string manipulation** methods available in javascript, along with **map** and sort array methods, I've create a sample code that works for me

```
let arr=['2022 | Dec (V2 2022)', '2022 | Jul (V1 2022)'];
let sortedArr = arr.map(x=>{
  let dtString = x.replace(x.substring(x.indexOf('('),x.length),'');
  dtString = dtString.replace('|','-').replace(/ /g,'');
  return {originalTxt: x, date: Date.parse(dtString)};
}).sort((a,b)=>{return a.date - b.date;}).map(x=>x.originalTxt);

console.log(sortedArr);
```

So basically what I did was, stripped off the text in parenthesis and replaced pipe character (|) with dash (-) character and stripped off empty spaces, so that the string looks like '2022-Dec, 2022-Jul', and converted this to date (now its convertable) and to keep the original string I created an object with date and originalTxt. Performed sorting with **sort** js method and showed the original text again. (It was sorted now)